# What's the optimal data structure to store a String grid in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, grid, coordinates, data-storage

What's an optimal data structure to store a String grid like this one and how to concisely convert the String into that data type?

`"""10 15 20 11
14 19 04 10
18 63 92 68"""`

I want to have easy access to any number from the grid by using a pair of coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [list](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) of lists like this:

```
val grid: List<List<String>> = listOf(
    listOf("10", "15", "20"),
    listOf("14", "19", "04"),
    listOf("18", "63", "92")
)

val elem = grid[1][1]
```

You also could write your own [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) and use it with [pairs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/):

```
fun List<List<String>>.get(i: Pair<Int, Int>) = this[i.first][i.second]
val element = grid.get(1 to 1)
```

**Update**

You could create list of lists from string with this helper extension function:

```
fun String.asGrid(size: Int): List<List<String>> = split(" ", "\n").chunked(size)
```

In this case at first we [split](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) our string to separate numbers and get collection of strings `List<String>`. And after this we [chunk](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) this list to get `List<List<String>>`

Usage:

```
val grid = """10 15 20 11
              14 19 04 10
              18 63 92 68""".asGrid(4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to say that my intention was to programatically convert from the String to your List of Lists. Because I know Kotlin can be very concise, I just don't know how I would achieve it.

Comment: Wow, it actually works. Didn't know about the multiple-argument split() function and about the chunked() function. Very clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can read each line as sequence using the [lineSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/line-sequence.html) and [split](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) the string using the " " (space delimiter):

Example:

```kotlin
val str =
    """
    10 15 20 11
    14 19 04 10
    18 63 92 68
    """.trimIndent() // remove extra indents.

val list = str.lineSequence()
    .map { it.split(" ") /*.toInt()*/ }  // performs intermediate operation (isn't done yet)
    .toList()  // performs terminal operation (performing map, and then convert to list)

println(list) // prints: [[10, 15, 20, 11], [14, 19, 04, 10], [18, 63, 92, 68]]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Didn't know about the lineSequence() function. It seems very useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.split("\n").map { line -> line.split(" ").map { nr -> Integer.parseInt(nr) } }
```

Here you first split your input into lines (getting you a list of strings), and then you map each of store lists to split them by the space. Then you may parse each of the strings inside, to parse them into an integer. This results in the end into a list of list of integers.

You might want to change the exact parsing to support more options (like splitting on all whitespaces) or parse into a different type.

Comment: Thanks! The map() function seems really useful. I was trying to tackle this problem using the forEach() function but it's actually map() I was looking for.